# iOS App with webview witout Fullscreen

Tags: ios, swift, webview, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I am quite new in the world IOS. I have a `WebView`. This loads a website. It is inside a YouTube player. The player starts right, but it always goes into full-screen. I tried with this code:

```
 Webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
```

But unfortunately it is not working. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on info from the docs: 
***"In order for video to play inline, not only does this property need to be set on the view, but the video element in the HTML document must also include the webkit-playsinline attribute."***

When you add your YouTube-video you should add the webkit-playsinline flag as well:

```
<video webkit-playsinline width="640" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
<source type="video/youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" />
```

Or as an iFrame:

```
<iframe webkit-playsinline width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=player_detailpage&playsinline=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn´t work. :-(

Comment: I tried it on the iPad . Here it does not work ... on the iPhone . Why?